# Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int in dateadd

Tags: sql-server

The following query works:

`select dateadd(m, -5, getdate() - datepart(d, getdate()) + 1)`

But when I tried to replace the `getdate()` with a specific date, example below:

`select dateadd(m, -5, (convert(DATE,'2017-01-04') - (datepart(d, getdate()) + 1)))`

I get the error saying `Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int`

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Nuances. Use dateadd anytime you are doing math on dates and never worry about this problem again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `GETDATE()` returns `DATETIME` datatype ,You Can do `-1` or `+1` with `Datetime` values but not with `Date` values.

If you just changed your query a little bit , convert to `datetime` instead of `Date` it will work fine.

```
select dateadd(   m
               , -5
               , (convert(DATETIME,'2017-01-04') - (datepart(d, getdate()) + 1))) 

                              ^-- Datetime instead of Date
```

Comment: Oh wow, I spent like 4 hours on this and would not even think of the `DATETIME` datatype. Silly me!